# Initial value does not appear as expected

Tags: c++, int

One of the first Stroustrup exemples in his book *Principles and practices using C++* reads as follows:

```
// read name and age (2nd version)
int main()
{
          cout << "Please enter your first name and age\n";
          string first_name = "???";      // string variable
                                                            // ("???” means “don’t know the name”)
          int age = –1;         // integer variable (–1 means “don’t know the age”)
          cin >> first_name >> age;      // read a string followed by an integer
          cout << "Hello, " << first_name << " (age " << age << ")\n";
}
```

The book says that by typing *22 Carlos* I would get as output **Hello, 22 (age -1)**, but, independent of initial value I always get a zero.

ps: Aside from this the program works as intended.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: tl;dr The behaviour changed in C++11 and you need a more up-to-date edition of the book